# Seaborn Violin Plot from Pandas Dataframe, each column its own separate violin plot

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have Pandas Dataframe with structure:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  4
3  3  7
4  6  8
```

How do I generate a Seaborn Violin plot with each column as its own separate violin plot for side-by-side  comparison?

Comment: I suggest to accept the other answer, as it is what most people will want...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can first reshape by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for groups from columns and then [`seaborn.violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html):

```
#old version of pandas
#df = pd.melt(df, var_name='groups', value_name='vals')
df = df.melt(var_name='groups', value_name='vals')
print (df)
  groups  vals
0      A     1
1      A     2
2      A     3
3      A     3
4      A     6
5      B     1
6      B     1
7      B     4
8      B     7
9      B     8

ax = sns.violinplot(x="groups", y="vals", data=df)
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 31):

`seaborn` (at least, version 0.8.1; not sure if this is new) supports what you want without messing around with your dataframe at all:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 3, 6], 'B': [1, 1, 4, 7, 8]})
sns.violinplot(data=df)
```

[image: violin plot]

(Note that you do need to set `data=df`; if you just pass in `df` as the first argument (equivalent to setting `x=df` in the function call), it seems like it concatenates the columns together and then makes a violin plot of all of the data)

Comment: Simple, yet functional answer. If I may add to that, in case you have more than just "A" and "B" columns, you can try to do this:

`sns.violinplot(data=df[["A", "B"]])`